# how to test for existing htm5shiv in source code using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec2

how can I test rails3 application for existing htm5shiv code using rspec?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
```

This is my demoapp:

```
rails new renderdemo
cd renderdemo/
rails g controller StaticPages home --no-test-framework
```

in **config/routes.rb**

```
root to: "static_pages#home"
```

removed public/index.html

```
rm -f public/index.html
```

created a partial for html5shiv **app/views/layouts/_html5shiv.html.erb**

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I rendered it in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<head>
    .
    .
    .
    <%= render 'layouts/html5shiv' %>
</head>
```

now when I visit my demoapp's source code I see partial has been added.

How can I verify with rspec, that rendering was successful? or may be check the source code that html5shiv is existing on each page?

Comment: There is nothing to test. Don't test external libs but the integrated results only.

Comment: I guess he wants to test that the library is included